# How to set absolute path for img tags to work in windows and linux

Tags: image, path, relative-path

I use a windows PC for my website development and (shared) hosting on linux. I want to use an absolute path for an img tag as it could be used in various different pages at different levels in my site (eg `http:/home/page1, http://home/level1/page2`). I'm sure you get the idea.

So I have something like `<img src="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/imagefile.png">` which I expect will find my image relative to the base directory of my website. This is indeed the case on Linux but on windows it will look in `/localhost/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/imagefile.png`, even though my website base directory is at something like `/localhost/users/name/webbase`.

I have searched high and low for how I might set the base directory for absolute img sources on windows, for example using a htacces file (I'm happy to have a different one on my windows and production servers), without success. RewriteBase doesn't work.

Any ideas?

(Btw, I have several websites so a global apache httpd type fix is probably not appropriate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny how the penny drops eventually! It dawned on me that I should be looking at my apache configuration. A little googling took me to the answer so I thought I'd post it here in case anyone else comes across this problem and expresses it as I did.

For any site you have on your windows PC, you need to set it up in two places. So, let's suppose you have two sites in C:/Users/user1/site1/ and C:/Users/user1/site2/ which you want to access via URIs www.site1.prefix and www.site2.prefix (I've used prefix so you don't accidentally confuse with a real site). The configuration you need is (this is what I have in my files):

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.site1.prefix
127.0.0.1   www.site2.prefix
```

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\https.conf** (this is where it is in my system)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site1.prefix
  ServerAlias www.site1.prefix
  DocumentRoot " C:/Users/user1/site1/"
  <Directory " C:/Users/user1/site1/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site2.prefix
  ServerAlias www.site2.prefix
  DocumentRoot " C:/Users/user1/site2/"
  <Directory " C:/Users/user1/site2/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you don't have any *DocumentRoot* statements elsewhere in the file outside of a *VirtualHost* pair.

Please be aware I only use this for local development on my laptop so it isn't production robust.